# python: make nested list based on elements on single list

Tags: python

I have a list of strings:

```
ls = ['elev', 'solRd']
```

I want to create a a new list, with nested list of two elements, where the second element actually better explains the meaning of the first one.

```
ls.out = [["elev", "elevation"], ["solRd", "solRadiation"]]
```

I have only few strings, which will repeat, so I would like to specify it manually.

Ie. 
if element is `'elev'` -> new pair item will be `'elevation'`;
if element is `'solRd'`->  new element `'solarRadiation'`, etc.

This seems pretty easy but I am relatively new to python and I cannot figure it our.

I have tried to subset my element by name `ls['a']` and include it to new list, but even the subsetting by name dis not worked.. I don't want to subset it by index, in case my string order will change.

Comment: Where do you expect to get the additional characters in the strings from and what have you tried?

Comment: it seems like a primitive task, if it implies some complexity - then clarify your rules

Comment: Please describe exactly what you want to achieve. Maybe a Dictionary is better suited than a List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
meanings = {
    "elev": "elevation",
    "solRd": "solRadiation"
}

ls = ["elev", "solRd"]

lists = [[item, meanings.get(item, "")] for item in ls]
```

Answer (score 1):

It would become easier if you create a mapping which would dictate the words that have to be added.

```
>>> mapping = {'solRd': 'solRadiation', 'elev': 'elevation'}
>>> [[e, mapping[e]] for e in ls]
[['elev', 'elevation'], ['solRd', 'solRadiation']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls = ['elev', 'solRd']
ls_out = []

for item in ls:
    if item == 'elev':
        ls_out.append(['elev', 'elevation'])
    elif item == 'solRd':
        ls_out.append(['solRd', 'solRadiation'])

print(ls_out) # [['elev', 'elevation'], ['solRd', 'solRadiation']]
```

You cannot name variables with dot-notation (`ls.out`). For python, please use `ls_out` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_2d_list = []
for i in ls:
    if i == 'elev':#or whatever
        new_2d_list.append([i,'the string i want for elev'])
```

same for its value you want